# HTML Agility Pack - Get Text From 1st STRONG Tag Inside SPAN Tag

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

There are 5 STRONG Tags inside my SPAN Tag from my Html document.
I want to know how to get the text from the first STRONG Tag inside the SPAN TAG?

Here is my code so far.

```
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(url);

        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='advisory_link']/strong");

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = node.InnerHtml;
        }
```

Comment: Already got the answer! :)

            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load(url);

            var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='advisory_link']//strong[1]");

            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = node.InnerHtml;
            }

Comment: Post your answer as the answer and accept it. That way you can close your question.

Comment: Make sure you test for null after calling SelectNodes or tag `?? new HtmlNodeCollection(null)` to it. Otherwise you'll get a `NullReferenceException` in your foreach loop if the tag isn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='advisory_link']//strong[1]");

        if (nodes != null)
        {
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                string Description = node.InnerHtml;
                return Description;
            }
        }

        return null;
```